# Is any connected fibre of a fibration of a sphere also a sphere?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Is it known whether, for any fibration of a sphere with connected fibres, the fibre has to be a sphere? $S^1$, $S^3$ or $S^7$?

Comment: No, obviously not, because every projection map $S^n \times F \to S^n$ is a fibration.

Comment: @Johannes Hahn: I think the question wants the sphere as total space: a fibration of a sphere, not over a sphere.

Answer (score 20):

It was shown in

Browder, William. *Fiberings of spheres and $H$-spaces which are rational homology spheres.* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. $\bf 68$ 1962 202–203.

that for any fibration $F \to S^n \to B$, where $B$ is a non-trivial polyhedron and $F$ is connected, $F$ must have the homotopy type of $S^1,S^3$ or $S^7$. This builds on previous work of Spanier-Whitehead and Borel.

Comment: Minor quibble: $B$ cannot be a point.

Comment: I think one should also add $S^0$ to the list.

Comment: Right, $F$ must be connected - I added this.

Comment: May there be a link with the fact that the possible dimensions of composition algebras are only 1, 2, 4, and 8 (Jacobson 1958)?

Comment: already found the positive answer in http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Adams-HI1.pdf